# These spaces are appearing to me suddenly while I'm writing my code, how can I remove them?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, keyboard

These spaces are appearing to me suddenly while I'm writing my code in Android Studio. I want them like this `if()` or `for()`

```
        if (  )

            for (  )

                Random random1 = new Random (  );
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a java or android issue. It seems like an IDE issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change Android Studio's settings if you want to use some inferior formatting style.